# Why is my Menu Router being rebuilt on every request?

Tags: routes

I have inherited a Drupal 7 site, and it is running quite slowly.

After enabling the Devel Query output, I noticed (not that it would be hard or anything) that there is a 65ms query `DELETE FROM menu_router`. There are also roughly 25 other queries, all coming from the `_menu_router_save()` function.

It seems to me that the Menu Router is being rebuilt on every single page request... Currently, our themer is rebuilding the theme registry on every build -- but that should be `drupal_theme_rebuild()`, correct? I don't see anything on [that function's page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/drupal_theme_rebuild/7) that would indicate it also rebuilds the menu router..

Additionally, I recently installed a custom module, and `hook_theme` would never actually take -- I tried clearing the cache and rebuilding the menu router, but I ended up having to add the values manually to the `menu_router` table. This makes me wonder if the `menu_router` table is even being truncated during this ~65ms query.

Does anyone know why my Drupal 7 site would be trying to do this?

Comment: That's definitely non-standard, the easiest thing to do would be to get XDebug installed, stick a breakpoint in `_menu_router_save()` and check the stack trace to see where it's coming from

Comment: I've tracked it back to `variable_get('menu_rebuild_needed')` always returning `TRUE`! Why would this be?

Comment: Check sites/default/settings.php for `$conf['menu_rebuild_needed']`, it might be overridden in there

Comment: It wasn't overridden - more debugging has revealed that there is a PDOException thrown every time it tries to rebuild the menu. It catches the exception, rolls back the SQL changes, and never sets the `menu_rebuild_needed` to false, because it still needs a rebuild. The PDOException is an "Integrity Constraint" stating that the `title` field of this query cannot be `null`. I am currently combing through a HUGE array that it spit out in the error log to see exactly what URL has a `null` title in its `hook_menu` and hopefully that will solve the issue.

Comment: The paths that were causing this were: `admin/appearance/settings/hooks`, `ctools/context/ajax/add`, `ctools/context/ajax/delete`, `ctools/context/ajax/configure`

Comment: @Clive So obviously 3 of these URLs are related to the Chaos Tools Suite. Is this actually a bug? Do I need to add the title parameter to their hook_menu? I would be very surprised if this were a bug in Chaos Tools that hasn't been caught -- so is my Database misconfigured by having title be a required field? As for admin/appearance/settings/hooks I don't get what's going on there, still looking for that...

Comment: Appears to be related to this: https://drupal.org/node/1118028